# French equivalent of "or else"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, oral

Is there any good translation for that English phrase? Something with the same general *sens* but different literal wording?

> Give me that cat, or else!

I'm specifically interested in a translation for *or else* as it appears at the end of an English sentence, as a threat/warning.

Comment: Example and elaboration added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both *sinon* and *ou alors* suit your needs, but it has to be at the end of the sentence, and you must somehow *pronounce*(!) the ellipsis-exclamation mark (you can use either a long-lasting sound or a very sharp stress on the *very* last syllable):

> File-moi le chat, sinon… !
>
> Envoie ce chat par ici, ou alors… !

The threat can as well be specified. Chiefly “*ça va barder*”. And *sinon* can also be completed with “*sinon gare !*”

Comment: Very true about the pronunciation of '...!' I'd like to add that "ça va barder" is rather France-specific. Westwards, we'd tend to use "ça va mal aller" or "ça va mal tourner", both of which promise bad things while staying quite vague

Comment: (+1) Excellente réponse. Anecdotiquement, et au risque de nous faire passer (nous autres lorrains) pour des rustres une fois de plus, j'avoue que je n'ai entendu *ça va barder... !* que dans le discours lissé des médias, notamment des médias datés ou pour enfants. C'est à peu près aussi courant que *Saperlipopette*. La seule variante employée ici au quotidien est *ça va chier... !*, voire parfois *ça va mal aller... !*

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you are looking for 'sinon'.

Example:

> Do your work, or else!
>
> Fais ton travail, sinon!

**EDIT: Since the 'or else' specifically refers to a threat, the below doesn't apply.**

<strike>Or:</strike>

> You should do it that way, or else, it won't work.
>
> Tu dois le faire comme ça, sinon, cela ne marchera pas.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I just saw the edit, geeze!

Answer (score 3):

The translation would be **"ou alors"** or **"sinon"**. But they are very rarely used at the end of a sentence, but rather to describe an explanation/alternative/etc...

Comment: +1 I overlooked 'ou alors' =P It works just as well imo.